# CakePHP - Pagination total count differs from actual count when using DISTINCT

Tags: php, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I have a find method that uses a DISTINCT clause to get results from my Model. The Controller code looks like below

```
$options = array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'fields' => array(
        'DISTINCT id', 'title', 
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Dealer' => array('id'),
    ),
    'paramType' => 'querystring'
);

$this->Paginator->settings = $options;
$cars = $this->Paginator->paginate('Car'); // returns 6 distinct rows
```

The above query return 6 distinct rows and 12 total rows. So when I am displaying, the screen shows 6 distinct rows

However in the View, when I use

```
echo $this->Paginator->param('count'); // returns 12
```

I get a count of 12

I checked the SQL Log and noticed that the count query is not using the distinct clause. Any idea how I can override the Paginator count query to use the `DISTINCT` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,

1. In controller add distinct as an array parameter with other pagination options. So if I was trying to retrieve a list of Cars in my inventory with 10 cars at a time, the options would have a DISTINCT clause in the fields parameter and a separate parameter called distinct would also be added as shown below

   $options = array(
       'conditions' => $conditions,
       'joins' => $joins,
       'limit' => 10,
       'fields' => array(
           'DISTINCT Car.id', 'title', 'user_id'),
       'contain' => array(
           'Dealer' => array('id'),
       ),
       'paramType' => 'querystring',
       'distinct' => 'Car.id'
   );

   $this->Paginator->settings = $options;
   $cars = $this->Paginator->paginate('Car');
2. In Model, use the below function to override the original `paginateCount` method

   public function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array()) {
       $parameters = compact('conditions', 'recursive');
       if (isset($extra['distinct'])) {
          $parameters['fields'] = 'DISTINCT ' . $extra['distinct'];
          $count = $this->find('count', array_merge($parameters, $extra));
       } else {
          // regular pagination
          $count = $this->find('count', array_merge($parameters, $extra));
       }
       return $count;
   }
3. No change in View