# cant get distinct rows from cakephp pagination join

Tags: php, cakephp

I cant get distinct rows of student IDs from this search.
I dont get an error and the data returned is correct as some students have more than 1 subject.
The reason for subject is to include a search parameter later so i still need the subject in the join.
This doesnt seem to do anything ?'DISTINCT Student.id'

```
 $this->Student->recursive = -1;

        $joinoptions = array(

             array('table' => 'students_subjects',
                        'alias' => 'StudentsSubject',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                        'Student.id=StudentsSubject.student_id',
                 )
                 ),     

           array('table' => 'guardians',
                'alias' => 'Guardian',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                'Student.guardian_id=Guardian.id',
                 )
                 ),
           array('table' => 'subjects',
                        'alias' => 'Subject',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                        'StudentsSubject.subject_id=Subject.id',
                 )
                 ),           

            );

         $fieldoptions = array('DISTINCT Student.id',' Student.last_name','Student.first_name',
             'Guardian.guardian_last_name','Guardian.guardian_first_name','Guardian.id','Guardian.guardian_mobile','Guardian.guardian_email',
                     'Subject.name','Subject.id'
             );

               $condionoptions= array(' Student.student_enq !=' => true,'Student.student_inactive !=' => true,'Student.tutor_gender_preference !=' => '', 

                      'AND' =>array(
                      array('OR' => array(
                                   array('Student.first_name LIKE'  => '%' . $searchFirstName  . '%'),
                                   array('Guardian.guardian_first_name LIKE'  => '%' . $searchFirstName  . '%'),

                        )),
                          /*
                      array('OR' => array(
                                   array('Student.last_name LIKE'  => '%' . $searchLastName  . '%'),
                                   array('Guardian.guardian_last_name LIKE'  => '%' . $searchLastName  . '%'),

                        )) ,
                        array('OR' => array(
                                   array('Student.student_mobile LIKE'  => '%' . $searchmobile  . '%'),
                                   array('Guardian.guardian_mobile LIKE'  => '%' . $searchmobile   . '%'),

                        ))
                         */ 
                        ) 
                       );


          $orderoptions =array('Student.first_name'=> 'ASC');             


        $this->Paginator->settings = array(
         'conditions'=> $condionoptions,
               'fields'=>$fieldoptions,
                'joins'=> $joinoptions,
                'limit' => 25,
        'recursive' =>-1,
                'order'=> $orderoptions,
               'page'=>1
               ); 

          $students= $this->Paginator->paginate('Student');
```

Sample Output

```
(int) 1 => array(
        'Student' => array(
            'id' => '216',
            'last_name' => 'Nipps',
            'first_name' => 'Aaron'
        ),
        'Guardian' => array(
            'guardian_last_name' => 'Nipps',
            'guardian_first_name' => 'Audet',
            'id' => '216',
            ..
        ),
        'Subject' => array(
            'name' => 'English: Year 7 - 10',
            'id' => '9'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Student' => array(
            'id' => '216',
            'last_name' => 'Nipps',
            'first_name' => 'Aaron'
        ),
        'Guardian' => array(
            'guardian_last_name' => 'Nipps',
            'guardian_first_name' => 'Audet',
            'id' => '216',
            ..'
        ),
        'Subject' => array(
            'name' => 'Maths: Year 7 - 10',
            'id' => '16'
        )
    ),
```

[CakePHP: How to make the paginator component use distinct counting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112599/cakephp-how-to-make-the-paginator-component-use-distinct-counting)

```
EDIT
  (int) 1 => array(
            'Student' => array(
                'id' => '216', //Only want ids to appear once and not twice as above, The above example has the id 216 appearing 2 times
                'last_name' => 'Nipps',
                'first_name' => 'Aaron'
            ),
            'Guardian' => array(
                'guardian_last_name' => 'Nipps',
                'guardian_first_name' => 'Audet',
                'id' => '216',
                ..
            ),
            'Subject' => array(
                'name' => 'English: Year 7 - 10',
                'id' => '9'
            )
        ),
```

Comment: Have you tried  recursive = 0 instead of -1.

Comment: that has no effect on this join and I dont think this is the solution anyway

Comment: what i am trying to say recursive -1 going to terminate all the relationships and join in cakephp.

Comment: from the docs as I have hasmany relationship Remember that you need to set the recursion to -1 for this to work:. Please forget recursive as an issue as i tried all variations

Comment: I think providing an example of working code is a better way to go as it doesnt appear an easy fix

Comment: What EXACTLY do you want? You have shared your code and sample output from that code (thank you!) Now share exactly what you would like. Also, why is that link to the other SO question at the bottom?

Comment: I want distinct rows of student ID. . If you look at my output I get repetition of student ID. Student ID '216' appears 2 times and I used distinct keyword in the fields.

Comment: Edit your question, and SHOW EXACTLY what you want the result to look like. (I assume you are using MySQL. If so, DISTINCT doesn't work on a column by column basis. MySQL's DISTINCT ensures identical rows (i.e., every column value is the same) are not repeated.))

Comment: ok i updated the code and added an example. I just want student ids to appear only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add group and this solve the problem

```
 $this->Paginator->settings = array(
         'conditions'=> $condionoptions,
               'fields'=>$fieldoptions,
                'joins'=> $joinoptions,
                'group' => 'Student.id',
                'limit' => 25,
        'recursive' =>-1,
                'order'=> $orderoptions,
               'page'=>1
               );
```

Comment: You have leveraged MySQL's unique implementation of `GROUP BY`. Be aware that the values from the subjects table may change between executions. [Read more...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: If you have a better solution then please post it. .